# Change member identifier of a type during runtime in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, member, identifier

Is it possible to change the name/identifier of a member of a user defined type during runtime, so that something like the following would be possible.

file.json: "{name: "Peter", nums: [10, 13, 1]}"

```
JSONDocument d("file.json"); // Parses JSON File
d.name.key = "other_key";
d.other_key = "Alfred";
d.writeToFile("file.json");
```

file.json: "{other_key: "Alfred", nums: [10, 13, 1]}"

Comment: I'm unclear on how you would write the code with names that you don't know till runtime.

Comment: Identifiers are meaningless at runtime. The computer does not care about silly human things like identifiers so they're stripped out during the build process and replaced by addresses and offsets from an address.

Comment: @cigien You can do that in some languages. e.g. JavaScript. It's effectively done by making _everything_ nullable.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Indeed. Perhaps my comment should have included "in c++", but I thought the tags made that irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create members at runtime in C++.